# how to fetch a data from database and store it in a variable in python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I typed this code but it's running but not storing any data in the variable.

```
if lg_id in list_user_id:
      fetch_pswd = cur.execute("SELECT PASSWORD FROM REGISTER WHERE USERID = (?)",(lg_id),)

cur.fetchall()
```

i have a table 'REGISTER' and in this table i have two column 'USERID' or 'PASSWORD'.

I have taken all `USERID` of the `REGISTER` in a `list` and searching a `userid` that is present in the list(means `userid` present in the list then it is also present in the `Register` table) and if not present in the list then also not present in the Database table.

then i want to fetch the corresponding `PASSWORD` of that `USERID`

Answer (score 0):

You doing wrong a lot of! Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html) to see details, it have enough examples. Correctly will be as:

```
 cur.execute("SELECT PASSWORD FROM REGISTER WHERE USERID = ?", (lg_id,))
 fetch_pswd = cur.fetchall()
```